# malloc(): corrupted top size when adding an element to a dynamic list

Tags: c, malloc

I am writing a dynamic list.
Here is the header file that contains the dynamic list and the function that add an element to the list.

```
#if !defined(STRING_LIST)
#define STRING_LIST

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct string_list      
{
    char **list;
    int size;

    void (*add)(struct string_list *list, char *string);
} string_list;

void add(string_list *list, char *string)
{
    int old_size = list->size;
    list->size += 1;
    char **new_list = malloc(list->size);

    if(!new_list)
    {
        puts("Error in malloc()");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < old_size; i++)    // assigning the elements from the old array to the new array
        new_list[i] = list->list[i];

    if (list->list != NULL)
        free(list->list);
    
    list->list = new_list;
    list->list[list->size - 1] = strdup(string);
}

string_list *string_list_construct()
{
    string_list *list = malloc(sizeof(string_list));
    list->size = 0;
    list->list = NULL;

    list->add = add;
}

void string_list_deconstruct(string_list *list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
    {
        printf("i:%i\n", i);
        free(list->list[i]);
    }

    free(list->list);
    free(list);
}
#endif
```

And here is the main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string_list.h"

int main()
{
    string_list *list = string_list_construct();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        list->add(list, "item");
        printf("new size: %i\n\n", list->size);
    }
    string_list_deconstruct(list);
    return 0;
}
```

The dynamic list is a struct that has two data fields and one function pointer which points to add function below.

And when running the code I get

```
new size: 1

new size: 2

new size: 3

new size: 4

malloc(): corrupted top size
Aborted
```

I used valgrind to chick for memory leak but I found nothing.

Any help?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings: *'string_list_construct': must return a value*.  The `return list;` is missing, so the caller's `list = string_list_construct()` is undefined behaviour. Although, it still crashes :(

Comment: *"I used valgrind to chick for memory leak but I found nothing."* - memory leaks do not cause your program to instantly crash like yours does. `valgrind` however should and will still warn you about different problems in your code like reading/writing to/from unallocated memory, which is what is happening in your program. Run `valgrind ./yourprogram` and check the output again, carefully.

Comment: `char **new_list = malloc(list->size);` is certainly wrong size.  Perhaps `char **new_list = malloc(sizeof *new_list * list->size);`?

Comment: Yes, totally wrong. Thanks for the help. @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: I totally messed that :'( . Thanks for the help. @WeatherVane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to differentiate between the `size` and the  `length` of an `array`  and you can use `realloc()`  if you want to expand an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strdup(const char *src) {
    char *dst = malloc(strlen (src) + 1);  
    if (dst == NULL) return NULL;          
    
    return strcpy(dst, src);                      
                                
}


typedef struct string_list      
{
    char **list;
    unsigned int length;
    size_t size;

    void (*add)(struct string_list *list, char *string);
} string_list;

void add(string_list *stringlist, char *string)
{
  int old_size = stringlist->size;
  stringlist->length += 1;
  stringlist->size += sizeof(char*);
  
  stringlist->list = realloc( stringlist->list, sizeof( char* ) * stringlist->length );
  if(!stringlist->list)
  {
    puts("Error in realloc()");
    exit(1);
  }
  

  stringlist->list[stringlist->length-1 ] = strdup(string);
}

string_list *string_list_construct()
{
    string_list *list = malloc(sizeof(string_list));
    list->size = 0;
    list->list = NULL;

    list->add = add;

    return list;
}

void string_list_deconstruct(string_list *list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list->length; i++)
    {
        printf("free() i-th entry:%d\n", i);
        free(list->list[i]);
    }

    free(list->list);
    free(list);
}


int main()
{
    string_list *list = string_list_construct();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        list->add(list, "item");
        printf("new length: %d\n", list->length);
        printf("new size: %ld\n\n", list->size );
    }
    string_list_deconstruct(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for there help. Now I understand where is my mistake.

Comment: Simplification candidate: `strcpy(dst, src); return dst;` --> `return strcpy(dst, src);`

Comment: Unclear why use `unsigned long` in `unsigned int length;`.  Consider `size_t length`.

Comment: `if( stringlist->length == 1 )` test not needed. Only `the `realloc()` needed, even if first allocation is `stringlist->list == NULL`.